# HTML/CSS need div to take 100% of vertical height of parent

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create a web page represented at this fiddle...

http://jsfiddle.net/jeljeljel/5BSva/

I want the vertical line for the left hand navigation under the tab to draw to the top of the footer sitting at the bottom of the page.

The footer features need to remain.  That is if the page contents don't take up the entire page, the footer remains at the bottom.  And if the page contents exceed the height of the viewport, the footer gets pushed down.

Can anyone solve this?  This one is challenging for sure.

**HTML**

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="header">
        HEADER
    </div>
    <div class="body">


        <ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="tabcontrol">
            <li class="active"><a href="#home" data-toggle="tab">Home</a></li>
        </ul>

        <div class="tab-content">
            <div class="tab-pane active" id="home" style="">
                <div class="navigation" style="">
                    navigation<br />
                    navigation<br />
                    navigation<br />
                </div>
                <div class="content">
                    content
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>


    </div>
    <div class="push">
    </div>
</div>
<div class="footer center">
    <div style="border-bottom: 2px solid rgb(174, 174, 201); background-color: #fff;"></div>
    <div>
        FOOTER
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.body {
    border: 1px solid rgb(174, 174, 201);
    border-top: 5px solid rgb(174, 174, 201);
    border-bottom: 5px solid rgb(174, 174, 201);
    border-left: 2px solid rgb(174, 174, 201);
    border-right: 2px solid rgb(174, 174, 201);
    padding-bottom: 1000px;
    margin-bottom: -1000px;
}

/* Sticky Footer by Ryan Fait (http://ryanfait.com/) */
* {
    margin: 0;
}

html, body {
    height: 100%;
}

.wrapper {
    min-height: 100%;
    height: auto !important;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto -50px auto; /* the bottom margin is the negative value of the footer's height */
    overflow: hidden;
}

.footer {
    height: 50px;
    background-color: #f8f8f8;
}

.footer, .push {
    height: 50px; /* .push must be the same height as .footer */
    clear: both;
}

form {
    height: 100%;
}
/* Sticky Footer by Ryan Fait (http://ryanfait.com/) */

.navigation {
    float: left;
    width: 150px;
    border-right: 3px solid rgb(174, 174, 201);
    padding-top: 10px;
    white-space: nowrap;
}

.content {
    padding-top: 10px;
}

.nav {
    margin-bottom: 0px;
}
```

Comment: Not sure why you are putting a navigation inside a set of tabs, but you could just use bootstraps accordion instead which would probably be easier

Comment: Maybe, but I dumbed down the actual HTML to simplify and highlight what I am trying to do. Perhaps if you saw the actual page, the design would probably make more sense.  Perhaps not!  :)

Comment: Posting a link to the full page might be helpful. There might be a better UX solution out there. I'm personally not a fan of widgets inside widgets. It hides the content from the user

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok done.

you just need to make your column positioned absolte and then adjust the rest.
here are the code you have to add in order to make this work.

```
.navigation {

    position:absolute;
    bottom:50px;
    top:65px;
        }
.content {
    margin-left:160px;
}
```

and [here](http://jsfiddle.net/5BSva/1/) is your updated fiddle (i made a red footer to make it more visible)
hope this helps
cheers

Answer (score 0):

If I understand what you want, you need to make a faux column !

http://line25.com/articles/create-sidebars-of-equal-height-with-faux-columns

:) Hope this helps and answer to your question

Comment: Yes, this may work, but I am looking for a pure CSS solution without the need for image hacks.  Also, this left hand nav div is embedded on a tab, so the faux column approach prob wouldn't work in this particular case.